# how to select table tag from ajax data

Tags: python, jquery, ajax, django

I am working on a django application. In the application a user can upload a csv file. That csv file is then processed with pandas and a html table is generated with the pandas to_html function. This html table is then displayed on the webpage.

To submit the form I use ajax to avoid page refresh. The problem I am facing is in displaying the table when ajax is used.

This is my code

**views.py**

```
def on_csv_upload(request):
    path = './csv/'
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'file' in request.FILES:
            handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['file'], str(request.FILES['file']))
            df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(path, str(request.FILES['file'])))
            table_heading = list(df.columns.values)
            table_content = df.to_html(classes='table table-bordered table-hover thead-dark', index=False)

            context = {'table_heading': table_heading, 'table_content': table_content}

            return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

**html template**

```
<form action="{% url 'csv_upload' %}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="mt-2 mb-2 csv_upload_form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" class="inputfile"/>
    <label for="file" class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-lg btn-block select">Choose .csv file</label>
    <input class='btn btn-warning btn-lg btn-block upload_csv_button' type="submit" value="Upload file" disabled/>
</form>

<div class="scroll_it">
    {{ table_content|safe }}
</div>
```

**index.js**

```
$(document).on('submit', '.csv_upload_form', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    csvUploadAjax();
});

function csvUploadAjax() {
    let $form = $(".csv_upload_form");
    let form_data = new FormData($form[0]);
    $.ajax({
        url: $form.attr('action'),
        type: $form.attr('method'),
        data: form_data,
        dataType: 'html',
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function (data) {
            displayTable(data);
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, err) {
            console.log("Something went wrong: " + err);
        }
    });
}

function displayTable(data) {
    $('.scroll_it').html(data);
}
```

The problem I am facing is when I try to display the table in the webpage.
The code for the table is inside `data: form_data`. But `data` also contains other html code which I do not want to display.

**This is the content inside `data`**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <!-- bootstrap -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <!-- fonts -->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Major+Mono+Display|Source+Sans+Pro" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- base.css -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/base.css">

        <title>Home</title>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/index.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/index.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>


<div class="container-fluid">
    <h1 class='mt-5 title'>Title</h1>
    <button class='btn btn-warning btn-lg start'>Start</button>
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-5">
            <div class="card-body upload_form">
                <form action="/csv_upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="mt-2 mb-2 csv_upload_form">
                    <input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='6ft25AdsMCwH1t4NubFsf8pHQchean05J3QM3HcV99C7wBZQ4XRbqEZXKit93H3x' />
                    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" class="inputfile"/>
                    <label for="file" class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-lg btn-block select">Choose .csv file</label>
                    <input class='btn btn-warning btn-lg btn-block upload_csv_button' type="submit" value="Upload file" disabled/>

              </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="scroll_it">
        <table border="1" class="dataframe table table-bordered table-hover thead-dark">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>RollNumber</th>
      <th>Present/Absent</th>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Day</th>
      <th>Time</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>student1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Present</td>
      <td>1/30/2018</td>
      <td>Wednesday</td>
      <td>12:34:05</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>student2</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Present</td>
      <td>1/30/2018</td>
      <td>Wednesday</td>
      <td>12:34:05</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>student3</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Present</td>
      <td>1/30/2018</td>
      <td>Wednesday</td>
      <td>12:34:05</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>student4</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>Present</td>
      <td>1/30/2018</td>
      <td>Wednesday</td>
      <td>12:34:05</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>student1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Absent</td>
      <td>1/31/2018</td>
      <td>Thursday</td>
      <td>23:34:05</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>student2</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Present</td>
      <td>1/31/2018</td>
      <td>Thursday</td>
      <td>23:34:05</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>student3</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Present</td>
      <td>1/31/2018</td>
      <td>Thursday</td>
      <td>23:34:05</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>student4</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>Present</td>
      <td>1/31/2018</td>
      <td>Thursday</td>
      <td>12:34:05</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>student1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Present</td>
      <td>2/1/2019</td>
      <td>Friday</td>
      <td>12:34:05</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>student2</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Absent</td>
      <td>2/1/2019</td>
      <td>Friday</td>
      <td>12:34:05</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>student3</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Absent</td>
      <td>2/1/2019</td>
      <td>Friday</td>
      <td>12:34:05</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>student4</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>Present</td>
      <td>2/1/2019</td>
      <td>Friday</td>
      <td>12:34:05</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>student1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Absent</td>
      <td>2/2/2019</td>
      <td>Saturday</td>
      <td>12:34:05</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>student2</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Absent</td>
      <td>2/2/2019</td>
      <td>Saturday</td>
      <td>12:34:05</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>student3</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Absent</td>
      <td>2/2/2019</td>
      <td>Saturday</td>
      <td>12:34:05</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>student4</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>Absent</td>
      <td>2/2/2019</td>
      <td>Saturday</td>
      <td>12:34:05</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>student1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Present</td>
      <td>2/4/2019</td>
      <td>Monday</td>
      <td>12:34:05</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>student2</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Present</td>
      <td>2/4/2019</td>
      <td>Monday</td>
      <td>12:34:05</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>student3</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Present</td>
      <td>2/4/2019</td>
      <td>Monday</td>
      <td>12:34:05</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>student4</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>Absent</td>
      <td>2/4/2019</td>
      <td>Monday</td>
      <td>12:34:05</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>student1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Present</td>
      <td>2/5/2019</td>
      <td>Tuesday</td>
      <td>12:34:05</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>student2</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Present</td>
      <td>2/5/2019</td>
      <td>Tuesday</td>
      <td>12:34:05</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>student3</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Absent</td>
      <td>2/5/2019</td>
      <td>Tuesday</td>
      <td>12:34:05</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>student4</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>Absent</td>
      <td>2/5/2019</td>
      <td>Tuesday</td>
      <td>12:34:05</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>student1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Present</td>
      <td>2/6/2019</td>
      <td>Wednesday</td>
      <td>12:34:05</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>student2</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Present</td>
      <td>2/6/2019</td>
      <td>Wednesday</td>
      <td>12:34:05</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>student4</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>Present</td>
      <td>2/6/2019</td>
      <td>Wednesday</td>
      <td>12:34:05</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>student3</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Present</td>
      <td>2/6/2019</td>
      <td>Wednesday</td>
      <td>12:34:05</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
    </div>
</div>


        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

My question is how do I target only the table in this line of code `$('.scroll_it').html(data);`

Comment: Since your view is a response to an ajax call, it should return just the HTML you need to update your page. So why are you returning the `index.html` template? You should just use a template that only has the table content in it. If that's `table_content`, then your view should return `HttpResponse(table_content)`

Comment: I am planning to add more functionality to the webpage after the table is displayed. So I want to stay on the same page. If I were to use httpResponse then I will no longer be on the same page.

Comment: but `render(request, 'index.html', context)` is also a `HttpResponse`. So what you're saying makes no sense. The response is received by your ajax call, so it can be ignored or used anyway you want, but it won't refresh the page unless you explicitly refresh the page in javascript.

Comment: oh ok. it just made sense to me. Thanks a lot. it works now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Returning `render(request, 'index.html', context)` is what causing this problem. 
You should return only the HTML you need.

But now you'll face a problem which is that you will have to write 2 view functions, one using `render` and the other using `HttpResponse`. In this case I would strict the `render` view to only return the page general layout and delegate all the `HTML Table` rendering and updating to `ajax` so it will be unified and initially load the table on `document ready` and update it as requested.

```
def csv_upload_page(request):
    context = {}
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)


def on_csv_upload_ajax(request):
path = './csv/'
if request.method == 'POST':
    if 'file' in request.FILES:
        handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['file'], str(request.FILES['file']))
        df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(path, str(request.FILES['file'])))
        table_heading = list(df.columns.values)
        table_content = df.to_html(classes='table table-bordered table-hover thead-dark', index=False)

        context = {'table_heading': table_heading, 'table_content': table_content}

        return HttpResponse(context)
```

Then normally load response into your desired section of the page.